# Papyrus 2.0.1 installation fail on eclipse neon (Release 4.6.1)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-neon, papyrus

*Eclipse for PHP Developers*

**Version:** Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)

**Build id:** 20161007-1200

```
http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/updates/releases/neon
```

**Papyrus version:** 2.0.1

I am currently using above eclipse version on windows 2012 R2 64bit environment and when I am trying to install Papyrus 2.0.1 plugin using above URI via Install new software wizard. This only download until 26% and not continue to complete. (Internet connection is working properly I have 2MBps connection and other eclipse updates working fine). Kindly advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-installed Eclipse Neon (executed eclipse-installer/eclipse-inst.exe from wherever I had previously had the eclipse-inst-win64.exe unpack everything) and selected to provision a Papyrus project during the install phase.

Prior to that, the Install New Software would report errors about not finding various packages (log message: "No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.core,1.2.0.v200908252030")

Various attempts at modifying the Available Sites (appending "/" to those entries missing them was suggested for a previous Eclipse release) ended up killing the Available Sites list, so I started over. After restart, Eclipse ran some updates and now seems to work, though I haven't actually made any drawings yet.